# How to pass form object as props to React function components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to do a multistep form, with a final form summarizing information that the user wrote in previous steps before they can submit.

But when I write into inputs, it doesn't display anything even if the console returns characters.

Here is a [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pdx78s) where I reproduced the issue.

What am I doing wrong, is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zaaf12) is working example.
First of all you need to store your `formData` in state using `useState` hook. You are using global variable and React wouldn't re-render the UI unless components `props` or `state`.

```js
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    form1: {}
    form2: {}
});
```

Then you need to change the state, I would like to use single function for every form state.

```
const onChange = (formName, fieldName, value) => {
    setFormData(oldFormData => ({...oldFormData, [formName]: { ...oldFormData[formName], [fieldName]: value}}))
}
```

Then, `PaymentForm` component would be something like this.

```
import React from "react";
const PaymentForm = () => {
  const [step, setStep] = useState(0);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    form1: {},
    form1: {},
  });
  const onChange = (formName, fieldName, value) => {
    setFormData((oldFormData) => ({
      ...oldFormData,
      [formName]: { ...oldFormData[formName], [fieldName]: value },
    }));
  };

  const onSubmit = () => {
    console.log(formData);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {step === 1 ? (
        <Form1 formData={formData.form1} onChange={onChange} />
      ) : step === 2 ? (
        <Form2 formData={formData.form2} onChange={onChange} />
      ) : step === 3 ? (
        <Form3 formData={formData.form3} onChange={onChange} />
      ) : (
        <Form4 formData={formData.form4} onChange={onChange} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Then use `onChange` function according to your form components like below.

```js
const Form1 = ({ formData, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <Flex direction="column" p={6} pb={0}>
      <Heading w="100%" size="md" fontWeight="bold" mb="2%">
        Customer
      </Heading>

      <Flex>
        

        <FormControl isRequired>
          <FormLabel htmlFor="email" fontWeight="normal">
            Email address
          </FormLabel>

          <Input
            id="email"
            type="email"
            value={formData.form1.email}
            onChange={(e) => onChange("form1",e.target.name, e.target.value)}
          />
        </FormControl>
      </Flex>
    </Flex>
  );
};
```

Comment: I would like to use other packages like ```react-hook-form```  or ```formik```. Easy to integrate and you can easily validate user input.

Comment: It's very clear, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you have to remove 'value' from every input element, because value is set to formdata value, it is empty string. turn this

```
 <Input
            type="text"
            id="lastName"
            value={formData.form1.lastName}
            onChange={(e) => formData.form1.setLastName(e.target.value)}
          />
```

into this

```
 <Input
            type="text"
            id="lastName"
            onChange={(e) => formData.form1.setLastName(e.target.value)}
          />
```

and do the same on every input element

Comment: I've tried what you say on form1, but it seems that inputs are still blank on order summary form 